# After orientation switch, TextView is no longer updating

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` with a `TextView`, created in the usual `findViewById` method, using the definition from my xml layout file.

I'm updating the text in the TextView using a handler, created in the `onCreate()` method.

When I switch orientation, the `TextView` no longer updates from the same `Handler`.

If my xml definition states a value for `android:text="blabla"`, then I see `"blabla"` in the view, but cannot update it anymore.

What's happening?!

Comment: You're going to have to post your code (abbreviated for just the relevant parts preferred).  This is almost guaranteed to be an order of events thing where the reference to your TextView is being updated to a new instance and your Handler is pointing to the old one

Comment: Post more code, and **never rely `onConfigurationChanged` as a last resort.**

Comment: Hmm, that seems likely. So is there any way I can keep a reference to the original textview in my onSaveInstanceState() method? I'll try and post some code too.

Comment: But... that TextView won't exist anymore, instead you need to create a *new* Handler and attach it to the *new* TextView. Or update the TextView reference in the Handler?

Comment: And how does one know what the handler's reference to a particular view is? Is that something we can access?

Comment: I think my example was too complex to try and post code here - there's various Handlers and Timers intertwined. The only solution I could find in the end was to make the reference to my TextView static.

Answer (score 0):

When u switch orientation, android create new view.
I'd suggest making that mHandler volatile.
If u decide just to use only one orientation, for landscape add `android:screenOrientation` in activity tag in android manifest

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot update anymore is because Activity reference is different.

Your first created Activity 'A', has handler 'a'.

Now handler 'a' only can update view that belong Activity 'A'.

So when orientation happened, Activity 'A' is destroyed and Activity 'B' and handler 'b' is created.

So 'a' cannot update 'B's view in front of screen.

For quick solution I recommend you disable re-create activity when mobile orientation rotated.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activityandroid:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if(newConfig.orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        Toast.makeText(this,"landscape",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }elseif(newConfig.orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this,"portrait",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

now onCreate will not be called when orientation.

Answer (score -1):

Try using,

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

  if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
      //your code
  } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
     //your code
  }
}
```

Comment: `android:configChanges="orientation"` is nothing more than a bandaid. There are many ways a configuration change can be triggered. For example, if the user selects a new language (i.e. the locale has changed), the activity will be restarted in the same way it does by an orientation change.